# Event handler not reached

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, events

I am unable to add an event listener to my button icons with class projEdit. I would display a new "page" whenever edit button is clicked to enable the user to add tasks to projects. The problem is that the code is not reaching the handler function. The button prints correctly in the console so I know I am targeting the right element.

HTML:

```
<span>Sample Title</span>
<button class="projEdit"><span> <i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span></button>
<button class="projDel"><span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></button>
```

JS to display new project: displayProject.js

```
function getProjectHtml(title) {
    const str = `<h2><span>${title}</span>
    <button class="projEdit"><span> <i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span></button>
    <button class="projDel"><span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></button></h2>`
    return str;
}
export default function displayProject(docRef) {
    docRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            if (change.type == "added") {
                const projectsDescription = document.getElementById('projectsDescription');
                let project = document.createElement('div');
                project.innerHTML = getProjectHtml(change.doc.data().title);
                projectsDescription.appendChild(project);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Buggy JS - to add event listener to the edit button icon: saveProject.js

```
function editTheProject() {
    console.log('hi'); // NOT REACHED 
}

function activateEditBtn() {
    const btn = document.querySelector('#projectsDescription > *:last-child .projEdit');
    console.log(btn); // This Is Fine!
    btn.addEventListener('click', editTheProject);
}

function saveProjectFunctionality() {
    // Step 1 - add project to DB
    const project = getProject();
    addProjectToDB(project);
    // Step 2 - Close the Modal  -  LEFT

    // Step 3 - Add event listener to the Edit button 
    activateEditBtn();

}

export default function saveProject() {
    const saveProjectBtn = document.getElementById('saveProjectBtn');
    saveProjectBtn.addEventListener('click', saveProjectFunctionality);
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons with the class `projEdit` (for multiple elements)? `querySelector` select the first element. And if so you have probably never tested the first button?

Comment: @SvenEberth Yes. I just realised that the event listener is being added to the second last element, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

After you said in the comments that the event listener is only added to the second last element, I assume you have multiple edit buttons and want to add an event listener to all of them.

You can do this like this:

```
function activateEditBtn() {
    document.querySelectorAll('#projectsDescription .projEdit').forEach(btn => {
        console.log(btn);
        btn.addEventListener('click', editTheProject);
    });
}
```

Otherwise you add the listener only to the first one.

Comment: But this won't be live...I will have to loop through the entire list everytime I add a new project.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. You need to provide more details about your code and where you are facing problems to add the event handlers to all buttons. I don't know your entire code, so I don't know when `saveProject` is called or a new project is added.